# Unable to locate package conky-manager

Tags: conky, mint

I want to install conky manager,I use 3 command to install it,

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

for the first command, ouput is:

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpfvhu7b/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpfvhu7b/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 2D0F61F0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpfvhu7b/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 2D0F61F0: public key "Launchpad PPA for Tony George" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

and for the second command, output is:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and for the thirdone output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package conky-manager
```

what is the problem? Is there another way to install conky manager?

Comment: Mint is off topic on AskUbuntu. As per the help section you need to ask this here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ Oh and here is your answer: http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ Your system is N O T supported. Please use an Ubuntu dist.

Comment: conky is working without any thirt party ppa for me in ubuntu. Refer this http://www.kushdilip.com/blog/how-to-install-conky-in-linux-mint-ubuntu/

Comment: @kushdilip , Now it's working fine for me too without any third party ppa in mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go the [ppa's site](https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ppa/+packages), you can download [this .deb](https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ppa/+files/conky-manager_1.2.0.1_i386.deb) for 32bit, or [this .deb](https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ppa/+files/conky-manager_1.2.0.1_amd64.deb) for 64bit, and install it.